# Way converting char array into NSString object with one more in the end character

Tags: ios, objective-c

code:

```
const char sbyte[] = {65, 66};

NSLog(@"byte：%c", 66);
NSLog(@"byte：%c", 67);
NSLog(@"byte：%s", sbyte);

NSString *string1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:sbyte encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"string1: %@", string1);

NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sbyte];
NSLog(@"string2: %@", string2);
```

print:

```
 byte：B
 byte：C
 byte：ABb
 string1: ABb
 string2: ABb
```

The correct application is 'AB', but now it is 'ABb', one more character 'b'??

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

All C strings have to be zero terminated:

```
const char sbyte[] = {65, 66, 0};
```

They don't contain any length information therefore the zero is a way to detect end of data.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you very much！ can I find this here to know more detail?